# Intelligent `\vref`

Tags: varioref

I want to use the package `varioref`, but using abbreviations `... (p.1)` instead
of `... on page 1`. Unfortunately, I have also references in
parentheses, where this would lead to unaesthetic/forbidden (?) double closing brackets.

I tried using `\@ifnextchar` to recognize this case, but this seems not to work.

Here, a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\addto\extrasenglish{%
     \def\reftextfaraway#1{\@ifnextchar){on p.~\pageref{#1}}{(p.~\pageref{#1})}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
In \vref{sec:test}, this is explained.
Other text (cf.\ \vref{sec:test}).

\newpage
\null\newpage
\section{Test}
\label{sec:test}
\end{document}
```

Intended output:

> In chapter 1 (p. 3), this is explained. Other text (cf. chapter 1 on
>   p. 3).

Current output:

> In chapter 1 (p. 3), this is explained. Other text (cf. chapter 1 
>   (p. 3)).

Comment: In my opinion, a simple separating comma would look nicer, and would avoid this difficulty.

Comment: @Bernard thanks for this suggestion. How can it be implemented? How can the space before the \reftextfaraway removed?

Comment: @Bernard I found the solution for the space before comma problem: `\unskip` fixes the problem.

Comment: Fine! Does there remain any problem to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I save the definition of `\vref` and then redefine it with two arguments.  I check if the second argument is a `)` and redefine `\reftextfaraway` accordingly.  I then call on the saved version of `\vref` with the first argument and pass freely the 2nd argument.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\let\svvref\vref
\makeatletter
%\addto\extrasenglish{%
     \renewcommand\vref[2]{%
       \ifx)#2%
         \renewcommand*{\reftextfaraway}[1]{on p.~\pageref{#1}}%
       \else
         \renewcommand*{\reftextfaraway}[1]{(p.~\pageref{#1})}%
       \fi
     \svvref{#1}#2%
     }%
%}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
In \vref{sec:test}, this is explained.
Other text (cf.\ \vref{sec:test}).

\newpage
\null\newpage
\section{Test}
\label{sec:test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this nice suggestion. I found two minor glitches: It seems that it eats spaces after \vref (which can be solved by either using `\vref{...}\ ` where spaces are needed, or using `\svvref{#1}\xspace #2` with the `xspace` package). In addition, it destroys `\vref*`.

Comment: @jofel I see that `\vref*` is to remove the space to the left of the citation.  However, I note that merely loading the `cleveref` package breaks `\vref*`, so I am not sure what resolution you might like to see, given that you load `cleveref`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying `\vref*` with `cleverref`. Please forget this part of my comment.

Comment: @jofel As to the space issue, your workarounds may be the best available.  By absorbing two arguments into the redefined `\vref`, any space between them is lost.  But I will think on it a bit more.